# Why need to add runUntilDate after the animation statement?

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation, runloop

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.animateView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        NSLog(@"animation finished");
    }
}];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
NSLog(@"after runUntilDate");
```

So many code like above，that's why? What will happen if I comment the runUntilDate line?

update：
If I add next line(NSLog) to the last，it will not execute until animation finished. Looks like runUntilDate blocks main thread, so why we need to block thread here?

Answer (score 0):

In you case, I think, nothing. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrunloop/1415778-rununtildate?language=objc)

Comment: Why runUntilDate can block main thread?And when we need block main thread like here?

Comment: Because runloop work in main thread. Ideally, you mustn't block main thread in any case.

Comment: runUntilDate just restart runloop's another iteration, why lead to thread blocking, can you explain at the source level?Thank you!

Comment: In you case, main thread blocking, because animations always works in main thread